# How to handle null pointer exceptions in elasticsearch

Tags: nullpointerexception, elasticsearch

I'm using elasticsearch and i was trying to handle the case when the database is empty

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <M extends Model> SearchResults<M> findPage(int page, String search, String searchFields, String orderBy, String order, String where) {
    BoolQueryBuilder qb = buildQueryBuilder(search, searchFields, where);           
    Query<M> query = (Query<M>) ElasticSearch.query(qb, entityClass);
    // FIXME Currently we ignore the orderBy and order fields
    query.from((page - 1) * getPageSize()).size(getPageSize());
    query.hydrate(true);
    return query.fetch();   
}
```

the error at return query.fetch();

i'm trying to implement a try and catch statement but it's not working, any one can help with this please?

Comment: Well, try and catch with `NullPointerException` doesn't seem smart. Maybe you can post the stacktrace? And maybe change the title to something more meaningful? "How to handle null pointer exceptions in elasticsearch" is just funny.

Comment: Shouldn't the easiest way just be to check if the return is null before you return it?